# Best practice to destroy class object from the thread started from this's objecs's method

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory-management, shared-ptr

So, so the title sounds mad, I think code will provide better understanding for my question

```
class Class
{
public:
    static void* thread_func(void *thisObject)
    {
        // do some work
        delete thisObject; // cleanup

    }

    start_thread()
    {
        auto worker = std::thread(thread_func, this);
        worker.detach();
    }
};
```

How to use this class

```
Class *p = new Class;

p->start_thread(); // start some work in parralel and return from function
```

So, I need to delete allocated object after thread_func is done. What is best way to implement such behaviour? Deleting thisObject from thread function as shown in the code sample works well, but looks as bad practice.

Comment: Allocation and deallocation shouldn't be the responsibility of two separate entities, worst in two separate threads. We like seing `new`s and `delete`s in a symmetric way. Better then, you should use smart pointer.

Comment: I have shown direct object removal just to be clear. How to fix my example to introduce smart pointers like shared_ptr or unique_ptr with move semantics? I have some ways but want to know best practice in my case.

Comment: The "best practice", as hinted at by YSC, is not to use `delete`, with the possible exception of inside the destructors of low-level classes that make it possible to avoid delete everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that.  For one thing, you haven't prevented anyone from stack-allocating an instance of your class.  You could do that, but it may just lead to more issues.

Instead, make your thread function simply delete internal resources held in the class.  But not the instance of the class.  If you need to, you can split your class in two--one to manage deletion of the other which holds the real state.

Comment: Only me can create class instances, so i can keep in mind to do not place object at the stack only allocate in heap as show in my example.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using c++11, use a lambda - then don't need to worry about anything..

```
class foo
{
public:
  void run() {
    // Do something..
  }
};

int main(void) {
  foo f;
  // construct and run the thread...
  auto t = std::thread([&f]() { f.run(); });
}
```

Comment: This only works because it's an over-simplified example: what if `f` is constructed where it can only be a short-life variable (shorter than the thread execution time)?

Comment: @YSC - for sure, we don't know what `foo` is doing, if the op made it clearer, then the solution would be clearer. No point in over complicating unnecessarily...

Comment: That's for sure. Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

Allocation and deallocation shouldn't be the responsibility of two separate entities, worst in two separate threads. We like to see `new`s and `delete`s in a symmetric way. Better then, you should use smart pointers:

```
class Class
{
    static void* thread_func(std::shared_ptr<Class> self)
    {
        // do some work
    }
public:
    static void start_thread(std::shared_ptr<Class> self)
    {
        auto worker = std::thread(thread_func, self);
        worker.detach();
    }
};
```

How to use this class:

```
{
    Class::start_thread(new Class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply deleting object in worker thread is a bad idea, because your thread does not know how object was allocated: int could be created using `new`, by plcament `new` in `malloc`ed memory, by some allocator, on stack, in static memory, etc.

You can add a callback parameter to your `thread_func`. In your use-case you will simply pass a fucntion which deletes object. But if the need arises, you can pass fucntions doing anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good place to use `std::shared_ptr` and in the scope where you are creating the object, use a `std::weak_ptr`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr